# How to remove background image in Cytoscape circular layout?

Tags: cytoscape

I would like to plot one graph with 40 nodes in Cytoscape. I plot it with a circular layout and got the following image. The yellow background is meaningless. I am wondering how to get rid of the background (i.e. change to white or transparent). Thank you so much.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's not a background.  Those are edges that are colored yellow.  You can certainly select all of those edges and hide them...

-- scooter